# Verify $J'_0(x)=-J_1(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I need some help with my math coursework. I am given a Bessel function, $x^2y'' + xy' + (x^2 − n^2)y = 0$, and I am told that it has two independent solutions, $J_n(x)$ and $Y_n(x)$. I am told I need to verify the title equation, $J'_0(x)=-J_1(x)$, by showing both $J'_0(x)$ and $J_1(x)$ satisfy the same differential equation. However, I don't know what this equation is. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Take the derivative of $x^2J_0'' + xJ_0' + x^2J_0 = 0$ and write it on the form $(x^2J_0''' + xJ_0'' + (x^2-1)J_0') + (\ldots) = 0$. Show that $\ldots$ is zero by using the ODE for $J_0$ and compare the rest to the ODE for $J_1$.

Comment: you were given the Bessel equation. $J_0$ satisfies the equation $x^2 J_0''(x) + x J_0'(x) + x^2 J_0(x) = 0 $, and $J_1(x)$ satisfies equation $x^2 J_1''(x) + x J_1'(x) + (x^2-1) J_1(x) = 0 $.

Comment: @Winther This is a few years after! Could you please elaborate on the last bit of the solution? So far we can show that $J'_0$ satisfies the ODE for $J_1$. But why $J'_0 = - J_1$ ? Can we justify the negative sign without using series?

Comment: @Saeed The normalization of the Bessel functions is a convention. It would depend on the definition one uses for these function (what initial conditions one wants to impose in defining $J_\ell$). In the usual convention $J_0(0)=1$, $J_0'(0)=0$, $J_0''(0)=-1/2$ and $J_1(0)=0$, $J_1'(0) = 1/2$. This info allows us to fix the constant.

Comment: @Winther Thank you. You are right: assuming the values of $J_0(0)$ and $J'_0(0)$ we can calculate $J''_0(0)$ from the ODE for $J_0$. Then, comparison with initial conditions of $J_1$ completes the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^2y''+xy'+(x^2)y=0.
$$
Differentiating both sides,
$$
x^2 y'''+3xy''+(x^2+1)y'+2xy=0,\\
\Rightarrow x^2 y'''+xy''+(x^2-1)y'+2xy''+2y'+2xy=0,\\
\Rightarrow x^2 y'''+xy''+(x^2-1)y'=0.
$$
So $Cy'$ is the solution of the last DE above. $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Letting $y=J_0$ you get the result you want. $J_0=CJ_1$. The Bessel function is actually *defined* in such a way so that $J_0=-J_1$. It is just a convention. So you should look back on you definition your examiers use, and find $C$.